# Vector field on $S^2$ with exactly one zero

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

My homework problem is to construct a vector field on sphere (and torus, but I guess I will be able to extend the idea if I figure out it for sphere) with exactly one zero. I don't know how to approach this so I'm asking for any explanation.
(Btw, this problem is from problemsheet on index of a vector fields, but I doubt that index would help somehow)

Comment: I suspect that you are required to find a *continuous* vector field with exactly one zero.

Comment: Take the sphere with center $(0,0,2)$ and radius $1$, for each point on the plane $z=0$ join them with the  point $(0,0,3)$ of the sphere. At the other intersection point with the sphere place a vector with the direction of the segment just drawn and length the reciprocal of the length of the segment. For the case of the point $(0,0,3)$ there is no segment, but put the vector zero there.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos, of course.

Comment: @ arts those wouldn't be a  tangent vectros, but "vector field" always means a section of tangent bundle, otherwise it would be easy, I would just take a normal vector field with appropriare length.

Comment: "vector field always means a section of the tangent bundle". Nonsense.

Comment: @ arts as far as I know, sections of arbitrary vector bundles are called just sections of bundles whereas sections of tangent bundles are called vector fields.

Comment: Just construct a vector field on the plane which goes to $0$ at infinity. Then use the stereographic projection to make it a vector field on the sphere (setting it to be $0$ at infinity).

Comment: Heuristically, start by considering a rotation of the sphere about an axis, with the vector field being the velocity of each point on the sphere. This vector field has 2 zeros, one at each end point of the axis. Now consider a homotopy of the sphere that brings these two points closer together, decreasing the length of the vectors between them as you bring the points closer together, until the vectors drop to 0 when the two points join. This leaves a vector field with only one 0 at the joined point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Puncturing the sphere $\Bbb S^2$ at a point, say, $N$, leaves the space $\Bbb S^2 - \{N\} \cong \Bbb R^2$; we can make this identification explicit, e.g., with stereographic projection from the point $N$. Now, $\Bbb R^2$ admits plenty of vector fields that vanish nowhere, and some of them can be used (via that identification) to construct a vector field on $\Bbb S^2$ that vanishes only at $N$.

Comment: Could you please show more details?

Comment: What more details do you want?

Answer (score 2):

I bet the reason this is included in a problem sheet on vector field index is that if you restrict to vector fields with nondegenerate zeros, by Poincare-Hopf your vector field had better have at least two zeros. To have a vector field with one zero on the sphere, it needs to have index equal to two.

Here's an example of a vector field with a zero of index two:

[image: dipole field]

To formalize this, imagine you're looking down on the north pole and use stereographic projection.